# Fragments in a table layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, tablelayout

Can i place several fragments dynamically in a table row and change its visibility on/off?

If there is any sample code , please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

To understand how to do that properly, please read how to add fragments using xml or programmatically to any ViewGroup (inccluding table layout): http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding

In the layout xml, you could put a `FrameLayout` with the id `fragment_container` into your table layout and call from java:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
```